# Leave message discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

I have a porblem. My leave message. There I have:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(
    channel => channel.name === "welcome"
  );
  welcomeChannel.send(`Hosgeldin :heart: ${member}`);
});

client.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {
  const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(
    channel => channel.name === "gelen-giden"
  );
  welcomeChannel.send(`Bye ${member}!`);
});
```

and then when somebody left then came <@id>.
I want to find his id because then I can make an link of the person who left.
It look like https://discordapp.com/users/732569703142129685 .
And then it should write 'Member' and this 'member' should be the link.
Please in v12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord returns <@id> because the member that left doesn't have more guilds(servers) in common with you and he is no more in your cache. If you need his id for some deletion of rows in db you can get it as `member.id`

Answer (score 0):

When a user leaves, he is no longer on the guild, so you can't find a channel on a server he isn't anymore in. You'll need to use `client.channels.cache.find()` in this case.
have a good day.

Comment: Check the docs guildmemberremove returns guildmember https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberRemove